# Conditional mapping to a dataframe based on multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, mapping

I have a dataframe where I need to map categories based on value-based conditions on two separate columns. Total rows to do this are about a million.

Sample dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['B','A','A','B','C','B','C','C','A'],
               'col2':[10,30,40,20,60,30,70,80,50]})
```

Now, the conditions for True are:

1. A: >30
2. B: >20
3. C: >60

If the value in col2 are as per above condition, then the result is True(1), else False(0).

Expected outcome is:

```
    col1    col2    result
0   B   10  0
1   A   30  0
2   A   40  1
3   B   20  1
4   C   60  0
5   B   30  1
6   C   70  1
7   C   80  1
8   A   50  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain masks by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df['result'] = (df['col1']=='A') & (df['col2']>30) |
               (df['col1']=='B') & (df['col2']>10) | 
               (df['col1']=='C') & (df['col2']>60)
```

Or:

```
df['result'] = np.where((df['col1']=='A') & (df['col2']>30) |
                        (df['col1']=='B') & (df['col2']>10) | 
                        (df['col1']=='C') & (df['col2']>60), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this as under:

```
df['result'] = np.select([(df['col1']=='A') & (df['col2']>30),
                      (df['col1']=='A') & (df['col2']<=30),
                      (df['col1']=='B') & (df['col2']>10),
                      (df['col1']=='B') & (df['col2']<=10),
                      (df['col1']=='C') & (df['col2']>60),
                      (df['col1']=='C') & (df['col2']<=60),
                     ],
                     [True,
                      False,
                      True,
                      False,
                      True,
                      False
                     ]
                    )
```

However, I do not know if this is the optimal way to do this. Other answers are welcome.